# Web view process shut down unexpectedly on IOS devices

Tags: ios, webview, memory-leaks, crash

Our app uses web view to render web UI, operating system occasionally kills this process. I know this can occur when there is high memory usage of the process - I am wondering if it can happen from some other reason? - or is there a way to get some more information on why process was shut down? - if memory is exceeded, for how much and what was the limit?

Currently main application process is notified through webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate callback - there is no additional info on why it was terminated - in some cases it happens after a minute or so of usage - there is no time to ramp up memory usage to be very high even if there were memory leaks.

I can cause this problem to happen sometimes if I use app for extended period of time - in other cases I see from the logs that this happens to our users after only couple of minutes or less of usage - not sure how to debug that further.

Comment: Xcode Instruments have dedicated profiles for memory leaks.

Comment: Thing to note here is I am unable to reproduce the problem locally, so xcode tools don't help. This happens to our users - I can see it in the logs.